# How to make multiples ajax calls simultaneously and asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have a javascript object called `Agendamento` that has these important parts:

```js
const Agendamento = {
   // ...

   storeResultados: async function (consulta) {
        //...
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<my-url>',
            data: <my-data>,
        });
    }
}
```

and in another place I have this another important parte:

```js
for (const consulta of consultas) {
    Agendamento.storeResultados(consulta);
}
```

my question is: WHY ARE THE CALLS NOT BEING CALLED SIMULTANEOUSLY AND ASYNCHRONOUSLY??.

**THE PURPOSE OF THIS**: As you may guess, these APIs that I'm calling take too much time to return data. So I know that these calls are not being called simultaneously because one request waits for the previous request, and then it starts, if all of you need some info, just leave it in the comments please, My head is burning out with this.

---

**EDIT:** Sorry for taking your time, it's probably a `PHP cURL` problem, question closed.

Comment: They should be called simultaneously and asynchronously? Even if they were, no need to tell in your question. I'd suggest checking your Network tab in DevTools. If they're actually being synchronously, there's probably a bottleneck somewhere.

Comment: There's no indication in the code shown that these would be synchronous.  Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs I also checked on the Network tab, was there that I discover that they are being called one per time

Comment: Are you just wanting to wait for all the AJAX calls to resolve before you display something?

Comment: @David on [Jquery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) they said that all jquery ajax request are asynchronous by default. the "A" from "Ajax" means asynchronous btw

Comment: @Andy no, I want to run all requests simultaneously, I mean, I want that the "Second" request doesn't need to wait for the "First" request to be done to start

Comment: @DaviMendesDev: Yes, I’m familiar with what AJAX is.  But in the question you’re claiming that it’s happening synchronously.  Then in your comments you’re claiming that it’s happening asynchronously.  Can you clarify the problem and update the question with an example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @David I will close the question, I think that it's not an AJAX problem. I realized it when I tried to reload the page and the page just didn't reload. Digging more deeper, I discovered that this API uses the `PHP cURL`. And digging more deeper (again), I saw that cURL blocks all subsequent requests until it's finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear from your question why your AJAX call is in an async function. `$.ajax` already returns a promise if you need it to.

I've used a fake API call here that mirrors your `post` AJAX call but returns values at random times so you can see how it works. The fake API function won't be called simultaneously because it's obviously being called in a loop, but the calls to the API don't have to wait for each other either.

As you can see they all return at different times whenever the code is run.

```js
const Agendamento = {
  storeResultados: function(consulta) {

    // Pretend this part is your AJAX call
    const rnd = Math.random() * ((5 - 1) + 1) * 1000;
    return new Promise(res => {
      setTimeout(() => res(consulta), rnd);
    });
  }
}

const consultas = [1, 2, 3];

// Here I'm just looping over your array and returning the AJAX
// promise, then I log the data
for (let consulta of consultas) {
  const promise = Agendamento.storeResultados(consulta);
  promise.then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```